# How to run a sample code which I get as input from Python GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a mini-project where I take a simple python function from the user using Tkinter(textbox widget) and then execute it and plot its time taken to execute with change in input value. How can I execute the code taken as input from the textbox widget?

Or should I go with some predefined functions based on general algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text from the whole `TextBox` with:

```
text = self.my_text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
```

And then run the code with:

```
exec(text)
```

But be aware than this allows the user to run ANY CODE he wants.

Comment: Besides the dangers of running untrusted code, it is unlikely that the execution of the code will be visible from within the `tkinter` application since they typically don't have standard input and output streams.

Comment: @martineau Don't have to see the output, if only the timing is important.

Comment: True, although no errors will be shown if there's anything wrong with the code entered into the widget (since there's no standard error stream, either).

Comment: @martineau, I'm very aware of that, and that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @ShwetanshuRAj Glad I could help! Feel free to [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you feel like it was helpful :)

Comment: @ruohola I am having another trouble with Tkinter widgets. I made some changes with the above-mentioned project. Instead of taking the program from the user, I have already supplied a bunch of general algorithms which the user can select via Radiobuttons. The rest of the project remains same about plotting its time taken. I also want to show the algorithm as output on screen. I am doing this with Label, as i have to show different algo based on selected radiobutton and i know how to change labels.

Comment: @ruohola The problem is sometimes label are too big for parent frame and I need to add a scrollbar. I have tried putting label on a canvas and then adding scrollbar but the label does not scroll. It would be helpful if you can assist with the code. Also if you have any better idea to implement this idea please do tell.

Comment: @ShwetanshuRAj You should make a new question, which describes your current problem clearly :)

Comment: @ruohola Hey I have tried to be as simple and clear as I can be ... please check out the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487805/how-to-fit-a-child-widget-when-it-is-larger-than-its-parent-container